# PHP variable inside a JavaScript "text change onclick"

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I have this JavaScript code inside a PHP echo

```
        function change_text()
            {
                if(document.getElementById(\"toggle_button\").innerHTML==\"Ver respuesta\")
                {
                    document.getElementById(\"toggle_button\").innerHTML=\"$PHP_VARIABLE\";
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById(\"toggle_button\").innerHTML=\"Ver respuesta\";
                }
            }
```

I need to insert the text of $PHP_VARIABLE at $PHP_VARIABLE, but it is not working...
I think this will work with this javascript code who obtain the variable, but I don't know how to insert this in the code.

```
var php_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have  a php echo as this you should simply concat the php var

```
<?php  

  echo '<script>
        function change_text()
        {
            if(document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML=="Ver respuesta")
            {
                document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="' . $PHP_VARIABLE . '";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Ver respuesta";
            }
        }
  </script>'; 

?>
```

Comment: does not working for me?
this is the error at webconsole:
Uncaught ReferenceError: change_text is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.php:34)

Comment: update you question and show  your real echo for function change_text()  <?php ..echo included   .. and i have update the asnwer  adding script tag for the code  ..

Comment: it insert a line break and don't know why
http://alvarod.es/publictools/nube/uploads/59f8dcf76cc6c/captura.jpg

Comment: answer  updated  adding doulble quotes around php var

Comment: it takes the variable from a line of a simple txt file and it have more lines, maybe is this the problem?

Comment: try use a correct text  (select the text portion not at the end ) .. or simply don't copy the newline ..

Comment: i'm using $variable = file("file.txt"); to open the txt and then I go to the line and using it at the javascript $variable2 = $variable[line] variable2 goes to javascript. How can I avoid copying the newline or not the end of line?

Comment: if you read  string from a file you have always  a string with a newline  ...but this is not relatead  to your original question ...

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as the second code block you showed; you need to echo your variable.

Remember that what leaves your server is not PHP, it's text. Javascript, from the server point of view, is just text, no different than HTML. You can echo out whatever you want, and it doesn't care. So if you want to embed a variable PHP generates into Javascript, print it out somehow, via echo, print, or some other format. Once it leaves your server, it's just text, and it's up to the client to interpret the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_text()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML=="Ver respuesta")
        {
            document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="<?php echo $PHP_VARIABLE;?>";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("toggle_button").innerHTML="Ver respuesta";
        }
    }
```